# Why is the upper bound exclusive in most RNGs?

Tags: random

Most programming languages provide (pseudo) random number generators and many of them have handy methods to generate integer numbers in a certain range. In all implementations I've seen so far, the lower bound of the range is inclusive while the upper bound is exclusive.

Is there a specific technical or historical reason for this?

I can imagine that it is just convenient when working with indices or lengths but I couldn't find any valuable evidence for that.

Comment: Don't know why, but it does seem to make the most sense. If the upper bound was inclusive, there would be a 101 possible values between 0 and 100. Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Probably due to using modulo arithmetics somewhere in the internal layers. E.g. if you have got one byte or random data your range would be 0...255. Scaling that to [0,1] would require a division by 255 which is expensive. Transferring that to [0,1[ just requires a division by 256 which is cheap: Just subtract a fixed value from the exponent in the floating point representation.

Comment: Note the related, ongoing thread over on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/296858/inclusive-or-exclusive-upper-bound-in-pseudo-random-number-generators).

Comment: @JTrana thanks for linking the posts :)